# Intellij Idea ignores maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a multimodule project and one module is a web app and the second one has a custom assembly.

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <formats><format>jar</format></formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cfg-src</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Basically I need this archive to contain maven project with sources and maven structure, no binaries etc. 
When I assemble WAR with maven i.e. mvn package, everything is fine. I use "src" classifier in dependcy. My WAR contains the jar with correct assembly. But when I deploy WAR with Intellij Idea (I created tomcat run config) assembly config of the project is ignored and I an incorrect one. How do I make Idea not to ignore assembly plugin. Please let me know if I'm clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ does not run `mvn package` when you deploy your webapp in Tomcat. It runs its custom *Make* and *Build artifact* actions.

You can change this behavior by going into *Run/Debug configurations* dialog and setting *Run Maven Goal* (package in your case) as a *Before launch action* instead of *Make* and *Build artifact*.

Hope this helps